# Create dmg with Retina background support?

Tags: macos, cocoa, retina-display, dmg

I need to make a dmg that support both 1x and 2x background, but there seems no info about retina in hdiutil or other tools like dropdmg. I create a normal one and it apparently blurs on Retina MBP. Any one have a solution?

Comment: It's not the DMG that has a background, it's the folder that has a Finder background image. So if you can find info on using Retina background images for folder windows in Finder, that will tell you how to do it in a DMG.

Comment: PS, as far as I know, the only supported ways to set a Finder background image are through the Finder's Show View Options menu item, or via AppleScript's "background picture of icon view options of theWindow", and I don't see any way to handle retina images for either one. Maybe if you set it to background.png and then add an "@2" file it'll work, but I don't have a Retina MBP to test on…

Comment: I would test this on the latest Mountain Lion builds; odds are if it exists now, it didn't then...

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi The latest Mountain Lion builds are simple dmg without backgrounds, so I think it wouldn't help.

Comment: @abarnert yes you are right, it's all about the .DS_store file. But I don't know if it's possible to add the pic by simply writing something to that file lol

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A guess: a multirepresentation TIFF file might work, see first paragraph of this [Apple link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH7-SW10). HTH.

Comment: Wonderful! I use dropDMG to generate the dmg, and it does support insert tiff as the background. So I generate the tiff, change its name to png, and output the dmg, AND IT WORKS! Don't know if dropDMG will update to support tiff as background.

Comment: DropDMG 3.2 adds support for TIFF files as background images. You can also give it any type of graphic file, and it will generate a multi-resolution TIFF (with the text rendered optimally for each resolution). http://c-command.com/dropdmg/

Comment: Just made a DMG background image using multi-page TIFF and it worked splendidly. We used the tiffutil command described on https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH7-SW13

Comment: Electron docs link here. This is the command you are looking for
`tiffutil -cathidpicheck background.png background@2x.png -out background.tiff`

Comment: @fionbio What resolution should the png file be when using your suggested `tiffutil` command?

Comment: @Nyxynyx This was a while ago, but I believe whatever you want. When working with Electron, I had set the window size to match the background size so the experience fits.

Comment: @fionbio – follow the link in the answer and scroll up the page a bit to *Run the TIFF Utility Command in Terminal*, it talks about the relative sizes of the images. Note: the sizes are in *pixels* and do not include a "resolution".

Answer (score 3):

TIFF files with 2 representations work as folder background images for Retina as expected. Mac OS X 10.5, 10.7 and 10.8 show a correct BG representation depending on whether HiDPI is available or not. Unfortunately 10.6 shows oversized high resolution representation instead of a normal one, which makes it unacceptable if you're targeting 10.6 as well.